# How do I find Xpath or Decrypt Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xpath, encryption

```
URL = 'https://www.sia.ch/fr/affiliation/liste-des-membres/membres-individuels/m/207778/'
res = requests.get(url)
selector = html.fromstring(res.content)
telephone = selector.xpath('//*[@class="contact-data"]/text()[1]')[0]
email = selector.xpath('//*[@class="contact-data"]/a/text()')[0]
```

I didn't find telephone and email because of javascript encryption

```
<a href="javascript:linkTo_UnCryptMailto('nbjmup+jogpAcbnbsdi/di');" class="mail">info@bamarch.ch</a>
```

Comment: Please read this page https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question.

Comment: What do you mean? The email address is right there in the markup. You don't have to decrypt anything. Since you're not selecting the href attribute but rather the text node you should see something. What is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no encryption at all. Slightly different approach to get this data. You may opt for this or may find the exact syntax.

I think your xpaths are incorrect in syntax but I'm not sure to be honest. I used selenium to grab the telephone and email and it work with ease.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Downloads\chromedriver.exe")

URL = 'https://www.sia.ch/fr/affiliation/liste-des-membres/membres-individuels/m/207778/'
driver.get(URL)

data = driver.find_element_by_class_name("contact-data").text
print(data)
```

Output:

[image]